# Frequencies of statsmodels.tsa.deterministic.CalendarFourier function

Tags: python, fft, statsmodels

As the title says, how many frequencies have the `statsmodels.tsa.deterministic.CalendarFourier` function?

As I'm trying to do a deterministic process like this:

```
dp = DeterministicProcess(
                index=data.date.unique(),
                constant=False,
                order=0, # Trend
                seasonal=False, # Seasonal variables
                additional_terms=[CalendarFourier(freq='Y', order=1)], # Fourier series
                drop=True)
```

But the only possible arguments for `freq` in `CalendarFourier(freq='Y', order=1)` that I have found so far are: `Y`, `Q`, `W`.

Where can I find all the possible arguments? Neither in the [documentation](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.deterministic.CalendarFourier.html) or in the [source code](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/_modules/statsmodels/tsa/deterministic.html) exist information about possible arguments for `freq`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

The DeterministicProcces freq takes a pandas frecuency string. You can check all the pandas's frecuency strings in
[here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#offset-aliases)!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).